# How do I get filepath and label of oledb object placed in excel using C sharp?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, oledb, xmlserializer

This is my first time in the site, so possibly I am unsure how to ask questions. Still here it is:

I have an excel file containing XML files in OLEdb object form.

What I need is:
how can I get the label and file path of that XML file stored in OLEdb using C#.

Note: OE1.name is not getting me the right thing.

What I have tried -

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xlapp = new Excel.Application();
    xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Vijay\\Documents\\File1.xlsm");
    xlws = xlwb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    foreach (Excel.OLEObject OE1 in xlws.OLEObjects())
    {
      MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(OE1.Name));
    }
    xlwb.Close();
    xlapp.Quit();
}
```